# Replacing a *specific* term in an XML file

Tags: xml, bash, sed, replace

I want to replace the text `PATHTOEXPORT` with the contents of a variable passed on the command-line that would have a folder path in it (for example, `/Dev_Content/AIX/Apache`)

I came across this [article](http://www.dotkam.com/2007/04/04/sed-to-parse-and-modify-xml-element-nodes/) that discusses how to use `sed` to replace a value in an XML file with another.

However, not having used `sed` before, I'm unsure how to read the directions.

The script is as follows:

```
# Check that exactly 3 values were passed in
if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
echo 1>&2 “This script replaces xml element’s value with the one provided as a command parameter \n\n\tUsage: $0 <xml filename> <element name> <new value>”
exit 127
fi

echo "DEBUG: Starting... [Ok]\n"
echo "DEBUG: searching $1 for tagname <$2> and replacing its value with '$3'"

# Creating a temporary file for sed to write the changes to
temp_file="repl.temp"

# Elegance is the key -> adding an empty last line for Mr. “sed” to pick up
echo ” ” >> $1

# Extracting the value from the <$2> element
el_value=`grep “<$2>.*<.$2>” $1 | sed -e “s/^.*<$2/<$2/” | cut -f2 -d”>”| cut -f1 -d”<”`

echo "DEBUG: Found the current value for the element <$2> - '$el_value'"

# Replacing elemen’s value with $3
sed -e “s/<$2>$el_value<\/$2>/<$2>$3<\/$2>/g” $1 > $temp_file

# Writing our changes back to the original file ($1)
chmod 666 $1
mv $temp_file $1
```

Is there a better way to do what I need to do? Can I do it *in situ* rather than using an intermediate file?

Comment: Yes, you need an intermediate file.  By default, sed writes to stdout, so you must capture that in your temp file.  If you try to capture that in the original file you will overwrite the file and lose the contents.

Comment: Oops!  I forgot about the -i option, since I never use it, sorry.  I don't think sed had this when I first learned Unix almost 20 years ago (if it did I obviously didn't learn it), and that bit of memory in my brain seems to be ROM!  ;->  As Brian Clements said in his answer, it has the potential to corrupt the file, so I'd recommend using a suffix for backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have sed edit in place. There are two options, have sed make a temporary file for you (safest) or really have it edit in place (dangerous if your command isn't tested).

```
sed -i 'bak' -e 's|PATHTOEXPORT|/Dev_Content/AIX/Apache|' file.txt
```

or for the brave:

```
sed -i '' -e 's|PATHTOEXPORT|/Dev_Content/AIX/Apache|' file.txt
```

Comment: I should also note that the direct option has the potential to corrupt the file if something goes wrong.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for! Thanks :)