# sed error "unterminated 's' command" troubleshooting

Tags: regex, debugging, shell, sed

I am building a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036832/replacing-a-specific-term-in-an-xml-file) that will, among other things, replace a pattern in an XML file with a folder path.

The `sed` command I am trying to use is:

```
SEDCMD="s|PATHTOEXPORT|$2|"
```

where `$2` is the command-line parameter that has the folder path in it.

This is later called:

```
sed -e $SEDCMD $FILTER > $TEMPFILTER
```

However, on running the command, I am getting an "unterminated 's' command" error.

How can I get around this? I've tried changing the characters used to separate the regex (from `/` to `|`). And I've tried quoting (in different ways) the command-line parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell is seeing the parsing the contents of `$SEDCMD`. If you’re using this from a shell script, including a Makefile, you should always protect all your expanded variables with double quotes.  The double quotes will force variable interpolation but protect any shell metacharacter from further interpretation.

```
sed -e "$SEDCMD" "$FILTER" > "$TEMPFILTER"
```

I assume that `$FILTER` and `$TEMPFILTER` are filenames? I’ve quoted them, too, just in case they contain evil things like whitespace or other sorts of shell metacharacters; bizarre, yes, but it’s been known to happen.   A regularly run `rename 's/\s+/_/g'` on filenames to clean them of whitespace, but for the others, you'll have to take a more careful approach; e.g., what to do with stars vs question marks vs brackets and parens, etc.

If you add `-x` and/or `-v` to your shell command line, you’ll get some trace debugging, which I think would likely have shown where you went amiss here.

Comment: yes - $FILTER and $TEMPFILTER are both file names (with no funky whitespace)