# using sed i cannot get the following to work

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

Im still trying to learn sed so please forgive me if this is an easy question.

I have an xml file as the following

```
<configs>
<config name="{subdomain}" protocol="rdp">
    <param name="hostname" value="{windows IP}" />
    <param name="port" value="3389" />
    <param name="username" value="{windows user to log in as}" />
    <param name="password" value="{windows password}" />
</config>
</configs>
```

I am trying to make additions and removals to the config section. For the appending i have the following

```
sed 's/.*[/]configs.*/<config name=\"'$SUBDOMAIN'\" protocol=\"'$TYPE'\">\n<param name="hostname" value=\"$HOSTNAME\">\n<param name="port" value=\"'$PORT'\" >\n<param name="username" value="" >\n<param name="password" value="{windows password}" >\n</config>\n&/'
```

This worked up until i added the `'</config>'` line. After that it stating that the 's' statement is not closed, can anyone help me with the syntax of this?

Edit - I tried to use one of the suggestions below by escaping with the forward slash `<\/config>` but am still having the same issue.

```
sed 's/.*[/]configs.*/
<config name=\"'$SUBDOMAIN'\" protocol=\"'$TYPE'\">\n
<param name="hostname" value=\"$HOSTNAME\">\n
<param name="port" value=\"'$PORT'\" >\n
<param name="username" value="" >\n
<param name="password" value="{windows password}" >\n
<\/config>/n&/' guacd/noauth-config.xml
```

sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command

this works with the following

```
sed 's|.*[/]configs.*|<config name=\"'$SUBDOMAIN'\" protocol=\"'$TYPE'\">\n<param name="hostname" value=\"$HOSTNAME\">\n<param name="port" value=\"'$PORT'\" >\n<param name="username" value="" >\n<param name="password" value="{windows password}" >\n</config>\n&|' guacd/noauth-config.xml
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed error "unterminated 's' command" troubleshooting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070478/sed-error-unterminated-s-command-troubleshooting)

Comment: I don't this duplicates that question. Though the problem is related. The issue here, I believe, is simply the unquoted `/` in the `</config>` part of the replacement. Try `<\/config>` instead.

Comment: Keep in mind that `sed` isn't a good tool for editing XML. Unless you make assumptions about line breaks that are required by XML, the `sed` code gets very messy. It's better to use a language (Python, Perl, etc) that provides a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

The `/` in `</config>` closes your `sed`. Look at this simplified example:

```
$ date | sed -e 's/./</config>/'
sed: 1: "s/./</config>/\n": bad flag in substitute command: 'c'
```

Doesn't work. `sed` thinks the second `/` (in `</config>`) is the end of the command, tries to treat the following `config` as flags (like `gi` in `s///gi`), but there's no `c` flag, so it chokes.

You can either escape `/` like this:

```
$ date | sed -e 's/./<\/config>/'
</config>ue Jan  7 19:59:19 CET 2014
```

Or use a different separator instead of `/` like this:

```
$ date | sed -e 's|.|</config>|'
</config>ue Jan  7 20:01:30 CET 2014
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but using the escape did not work as well as trying a different separator, results in the same error.

Comment: What exactly are the values of `$SUBDOMAIN`, `$PORT`, and `$TYPE`? Can you give me examples where the script doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You've got `'$SUBDOMAIN'` in your patter, which closes the first single quote that defines the script. Try removing the single quotes from inside your script.

Comment: I use the single quotes to exit and grab the variable.